# Saving issue in mongodb C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, anonymous-types

this is the structure of Class,

```
public class TestClass
{
    [BsonId]               
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string _Id { get; set; }              
    public List<TemplateValuesNew> TemplateValues { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateValuesNew
{
    public string controlId { get; set; }     
    public List<object> TemplateValue { get; set; }
}
```

Save is working fine when

`List<object> TemplateValue` is simple. but for complex type like

```
{[
  {
    "FieldName": "New Attr",
    "FieldValue": "one"
  },
  {
    "FieldName": "New Attrs",
    "FieldValue": "two"
  },
  {
    "FieldName": "New Attr",
    "FieldValue": "thre"
  },
  {
    "FieldName": "New Attrs",
    "FieldValue": "four"
  }
]
```

it is saving but with some different data format why is it so?

Other formats may be like string array or single string values are getting saved

```
[{"firstvalue","secondvalue"}] or can be [{"singlevalue"}]
```

Comment: What is the "different data format" ? What does it look like?

Comment: @Fildor like this {"valueone","valuetwo","valuethree"} or can be {"singlevalueonly"}

Comment: Please add that info to the question, not in comment.